# regex for adding text - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have:

```
<span id="test"><a href="google.com/">link1</a></span>

<br />
<br />
<span class="click" id=1>click one</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=2>click two</span> <br />
<span class="click" id=3>click three</span> <br />

$(".click").live('click', function() {    
    $("a").attr('href',$("a").attr('href')+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/wtAbp/10/

if i click one i have:

**google.com/1**

this is ok, but if i again click, for example click two i have:

**google.com/12**

instead of:

**google.com/2**

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
$("a").attr('href', 'http://google.com/'+$(this).attr('id'));
```

Or

```
$("a").attr('href', $("a").attr('href').replace(/\d*$/, $(this).attr('id')));
```

Answer (score 1):

problem is you are using

```
$("a").attr('href',$("a").attr('href')+$(this).attr('id'));
```

after updation of link first time a herf is google.com/1

so when you query it next time remove the value after / from the link

Second time

```
var href = $("a").attr('href').substring(0,$("a").attr('href').lastIndexOf('/'))
```

final code

```
    $(".click").live('click', function() { 
        var href ;
if ( $("a").attr('href').substring(0,$("a").attr('href').lastIndexOf('/')) >0)
  href= $("a").attr('href').substring(0,$("a").attr('href').lastIndexOf('/'));   
else 
  href= $("a").attr('href'); 
        $("a").attr('href',href + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a data field to hold the original URL -

```
<span id="test"><a data-url="google.com/" href="google.com/">link1</a></span>
```

Then change your jQuery code to look up the data attribute rather than the `href` -

```
$(".click").live('click', function() {    
    $("a").attr('href',$("a").data('url')+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hz6Fr/